# paginate_links adds strong element

Tags: paginate-links

I just faced a strange issue with `paginate_links` in WordPress 3.8.1. The navigation itself works great and as expected.

But when going to the last page, it adds `<strong>` tags to the whole markup:

```
global $wp_query;

$unlikely_number = 99999999;

$args = array('total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
              'base' => str_replace($unlikely_number, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($unlikely_number))),
              'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
              'format' => '/page/%#%',
              'prev_text' => 'PREV',
              'next_text' => 'NEXT',
              'type' => 'list',
              'end_size' => 2,
              'mid_size' => 2);

echo paginate_links($args);
```

Here is the generated HTML with screenshots.

[image: page name as needed]

```
<div class="pagenavi">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
        <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
        <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://scott-odlo.csundm.com/page/2/">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://scott-odlo.csundm.com/page/3/">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="http://scott-odlo.csundm.com/page/2/">NEXT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: page navi with strong tag in last page]

```
<div class="pagenavi">
    <ul class="page-numbers">
        <strong>
            <li><a class="prev page-numbers" href="http://scott-odlo.csundm.com/page/2/">PREV</a></li>
            <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://scott-odlo.csundm.com/page/1/">1</a></li>
            <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://scott-odlo.csundm.com/page/2/">2</a></li>
            <li><span class="page-numbers current">3</span></li>
        </strong>
    </ul>
    <strong>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Does anybody know this issue or could imagine a fix for that?

Comment: is that the direct html code from the last page in the browser, or viewed by a browser inspection tool? does the last page validate?

Comment: ^ that's a good question above. Some browser inspector tools try to fix the code for you and sometimes ended up adding tags where they don't belong. Look at the actual source and see what the structure looks like.

Comment: Good point! And actually right! I found that the `the_content` filter adds unclosed HTML tags. In the text editor in WP the post does not contain any HTML at all. But on the frontend, after applying `the_content`, one post contains an open `<strong>`. Thanks, but I cannot fix it yet :(